# Why am I not able to list Java resources in unit test?

Tags: java

I have some files within `src/main/resources` that I wish to copy out to the filesystem.  I want to get a list of those resources, then iterate through them and copy them out.  I am using v0.9.11 of [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) to parse the resources directory.

```
public List<String> getMyResources() {
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ResourcesScanner());
    Set<String> resources = reflections.getResources(Pattern.compile(".*"));
    return new ArrayList<>(resources);
}
```

I want to test that I can find the files as part of a unit test:

```
@Test
public void getMyResources_returnsCorrectFiles() throws IOException {
    MyResourceFinder finder = new MyResourceFinder();

    List<String> resources = finder.getMyResources();
    assertEquals(3, resources.size());
    // other tests to check the files are found
}
```

However, there are no resources found, i.e. the `resources` array is of 0 length.  This is also the case when I put test resources into `src/test/resources`.  However, I can find and read individual resources by name like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/to/my/resource.yaml")));
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I list resources?

EDIT: to be clear, I can see the resources listed in the jar that is built.  However, my unit test cannot list the resources in `src/main/resources` and I'd like to know why that is and how to make them appear in the resource array.

Comment: Look at the contents of your jar file, notice how maven ***packages*** resources differs from your expectations. Correct your code accordingly. Note test resources are not packaged in your jar (because they are considered transient).

Comment: I can see the files in the jar, and they do follow my expectations.  However, when I run the unit test, the resources are not found - I don't understand why they don't appear.

Comment: Check this project, solves resources folder scanning: https://github.com/fraballi/resources-folder-scanner

Answer (score 1):

Can you check how you are initalizing your `Reflections` object?

### Reflections 0.9.11

If I use Reflections (v0.9.11) the way you describe in your question...

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ResourcesScanner());
```

...then I can recreate this issue - and I get a Reflections `WARN`ing. In my jUnit test, I expected to find 17 resources, but found none:

```
2020-03-11 14:54:59.039 [WARN ] [main] Reflections - given scan urls are empty. set urls in the configuration
...
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<17> but was:<0>
```

However, if I change my code to this...

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("your.package.name.here"))
        .setScanners(new ResourcesScanner()));
```

...then I get this:

```
2020-03-11 14:52:54.107 [INFO ] [main] Reflections - Reflections took 10 ms to scan 2 urls, producing 17 keys and 17 values
```

And my unit test passes.

### Reflections 0.9.12

Out of interest, if you upgrade to 0.9.12, your approach throws the same warning, but also a runtime exception:

```
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: Scanner ResourcesScanner was not configured
```